# how to navigate to the source file when debugging js in google chrome

Tags: javascript, source-maps

I am using the google chrome to debugging the javascript source file, now I could debbugging the output js file, but the output js file is not human friendly readable. It looks like this:

[image]

from the google chrome console, I can see the call stack, and the google chrome tips shows that the source map are avaliable. But how to navigate the the js source file with current debugging line? I already type command + P in macOS but just shows the source files, I did not know which line should to navigate. the call stack only show the output js file line number.

Comment: Did you try to reload the page after opening debugger tools? Try to execute the part of the app which triggers the code you have written. It should pause at the debug point 23487 line you have set.

Answer (score 1):

Next to the "Page" tab (you can make the side bar bigger or click on those two arrows, there you will find the "Filesystem tab". If you add the corresponding folder to the workspace you will be able to edit and save those files.

Here's [an article](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/workspaces/) that explains it in details using a python server.

[image: tabs menu]

(note that you can use any local server you'd like)

[image: filesystem menu]

(note that it won't work with local files url like file:///)

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to debug your current JS file at line 23487, steps would be to-

1. Load URL.
2. Open chrome debugger tools.
3. Put debug point on desired line.
4. Reload the URL, the debugger will pause at debug point.

You can watch below video for this, specifically @10:40 timestamp.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WmVEddplwbo

Comment: I want to debbuging the original source code, the common.js is not human friendly, I did not know where is going wrong from the common.js file.@Aakriti Gupta

Comment: What is the name of file having original source code you want to debug? After loading the app you should be able to see that file in your sources tab. If it is not shown, that means your js file is not properly linked to your html. @Dolphin

Comment: Provide more screenshots of your directory structure where you are developing v/s what you see in sources tab. @Dolphin